# How to detect negative sentences with sentimentr or qdap

Tags: r

I am trying to extract (and eventually categorise) sentences from medical reports that contain negatives. An example is something like:

```
samples<-c('There is no evidence of a lump','Neither a contusion nor a scar was seen','No inflammation was evident','We found generalised badness here')
```

I am trying to use the `sentimentr` package as it seems it is able to detect negators. Is there a way of just using the detection of negators so that negative sentences are extracted out (preferably into a new dataframe for further work)?

Using `polarity` from `qdap` just gives a summary statistic and is based on including amplifiers and deamplifiers which I dont want to include eg.

```
polarity(samples,negators = qdapDictionaries::negation.words)

      all total.sentences total.words ave.polarity sd.polarity stan.mean.polarity
1 all               4          24        0.213       0.254              0.842
```

I tried the sentimentr package as follows:

`extract_sentiment_terms(MyColonData$Endo_ResultText,polarity_dt = lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers, hyphen = "")`

and this gives me neutral, negative and positive words:

```
   element_id sentence_id     negative positive
1:          1           1                      
2:          2           1         scar         
3:          3           1 inflammation  evident
4:          4           1      badness    found
```

but I am really looking for sentences that contain negators ***only*** without interpretation of the sentiment so that the output is:

```
element_id sentence_id                          negative                    positive
1:          1           1     There is no evidence of a lump                 
2:          2           1     Neither a contusion nor a scar was seen       
3:          3           1     No inflammation was evident
4:          4           1                                               We found generalised badness here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to classify the text positive and negative only based on the presence of `negator` hence extracting negator from `lexicon` should help.

```
samples<-c('There is no evidence of a lump','Neither a contusion nor a scar was seen','No inflammation was evident','We found generalised badness here')


polarity <- data.frame(text = samples, pol = NA)

polarity$pol <- ifelse(grepl(paste(lexicon::hash_valence_shifters[y==1]$x,collapse = '|'), tolower(samples)),'Negative','Positive')

polarity

                                     text      pol
1          There is no evidence of a lump Negative
2 Neither a contusion nor a scar was seen Negative
3             No inflammation was evident Negative
4       We found generalised badness here Positive
```

Formatted OP:

```
reshape2::dcast(polarity,text~pol) 



                                     text Negative Positive
1 Neither a contusion nor a scar was seen Negative     <NA>
2             No inflammation was evident Negative     <NA>
3          There is no evidence of a lump Negative     <NA>
4       We found generalised badness here     <NA> Positive
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to extract whole sentences if one of their words matches either a positive or negative annotation in the `lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers`. For this case you can use below code (might be tuned up by using `data.table` in the interim steps if needed).  I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
library(lexicon)
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

#check the content of the lexicon
lex <- copy(lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers)
#             x     y
# 1:     abandon -0.75
# 2:   abandoned -0.50
# 3:   abandoner -0.25
# 4: abandonment -0.25
# 5:    abandons -1.00
# ---                  
#   10735:     zealous  0.40
# 10736:      zenith  0.40
# 10737:        zest  0.50
# 10738:      zombie -0.25
# 10739:     zombies -0.25

#only consider binary positive or negative
pos <- lex[y > 0]
neg <- lex[y < 0]

samples <-c('There is no evidence of a lump'
           ,'Neither a contusion nor a scar was seen'
           ,'No inflammation was evident'
           ,'We found generalised badness here')

#get ids of the samples that inlcude positve/negative terms
samples_pos <- which(stri_detect_regex(samples, paste(pos[,x], collapse = "|")))
samples_neg <- which(stri_detect_regex(samples, paste(neg[,x], collapse = "|")))

#set up data.frames with all positive/negative samples and their ids
df_pos <- data.frame(sentence_id = samples_pos, positive = samples[samples_pos])
df_neg <- data.frame(sentence_id = samples_neg, negative = samples[samples_neg])

#combine the sets
rbindlist(list(df_pos, df_neg), use.names = TRUE, fill = T)
# sentence_id                          positive                                negative
# 1:           3       No inflammation was evident                                      NA
# 2:           4 We found generalised badness here                                      NA
# 3:           2                                NA Neither a contusion nor a scar was seen
# 4:           3                                NA             No inflammation was evident
# 5:           4                                NA       We found generalised badness here


#the first sentence is missing, since none of its words is inlcuded in
#the lexcicon, you might use stemming, etc. to increase coverage
any(grepl("evidence", lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers[,x]))
#[1] FALSE
```